# How to get latest record on the top using DESC but the records come from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My query:

```
SELECT
crb_issues.id,
crb_issues.title,
crb_issues.volume,
crb_issues.number,
crb_issues.publish_date,
crb_issues.is_publish,
crb_issues.pdfFile,
crb_issues.flyer,
crb_issues.cover,
crb_issues.`status`,
crb_issues.issueType,
crbissue_data.typeValue,
crbissue_data.typeFieldname,
crbissue_data.typeData,
crbissue_data.issueId,
crbissue_data.id
FROM
crb_issues
INNER JOIN crbissue_data ON crb_issues.id = crbissue_data.issueId
WHERE
crb_issues.is_publish = '1' AND crb_issues.issueType = '0'
```

My table data:

```
150 testt   testt   testt   1389222000  1   13892477815300FMcmp1_2_2.pdf    0e3330b88c8c84c5470796b7c300592f734750465_1_1_3.jpg         0   Books in Briefs sel_crbtype_1387799449  a:1:{i:0;s:2:"80";} 150 12
150 testt   testt   testt   1389222000  1   13892477815300FMcmp1_2_2.pdf    0e3330b88c8c84c5470796b7c300592f734750465_1_1_3.jpg         0   Correspondence  sel_crbtype_1387799463  a:1:{i:0;s:2:"76";} 150 13
150 testt   testt   testt   1389222000  1   13892477815300FMcmp1_2_2.pdf    0e3330b88c8c84c5470796b7c300592f734750465_1_1_3.jpg         0   Essays  sel_crbtype_1387799485  a:4:{i:0;s:2:"54";i:1;s:2:"55";i:2;s:2:"59";i:3;s:2:"58";}  150 14
151 testnew testnew testnew     1   13892478715300FMcmp1_2_2.pdf    0e3330b88c8c84c5470796b7c300592f734750465_1_1_4.jpg         0   Essays  sel_crbtype_1387799485  a:2:{i:0;s:2:"56";i:1;s:2:"57";}    151 15
151 testnew testnew testnew     1   13892478715300FMcmp1_2_2.pdf    0e3330b88c8c84c5470796b7c300592f734750465_1_1_4.jpg         0   Reviews of Books    sel_crbtype_1387799512  a:4:{i:0;s:2:"60";i:1;s:2:"61";i:2;s:2:"81";i:3;s:2:"62";}  151 16
151 testnew testnew testnew     1   13892478715300FMcmp1_2_2.pdf    0e3330b88c8c84c5470796b7c300592f734750465_1_1_4.jpg         0   Parthian Shot   sel_crbtype_1387799533  a:3:{i:0;s:2:"64";i:1;s:2:"66";i:2;s:2:"68";}   151 17
```

Now from above code I simply want the id 151 only from current scenario that is my latest inserted id from the database. I want 151 and its 3 record sets as well.

Comment: Have you tried something easy as an Order By crb_issues.id DESC ?

Comment: @Goikiu yes i have tried already but it is not fetch 3 record sets. it only shows one line record set. i want the record should beh order by desc by id 151 with its 3 record set as well...

Comment: Strange, normally if you put the "order" after the where clause it will order all sets obtained.

Comment: What about `WHERE ... AND crb_issues.id = (SELECT MAX id FROM crb_issues)`? Did you even try anything like `ORDER BY` or `WHERE ...`? And please stop posting useless comments!

Comment: the records is now descBUT how can i get only 151 record set not 150.. means i need rows having 151 id. thats it please.

Comment: @OcasoProtal it says [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'MAX' in 'field list' and sorry please. i am much nervous buddy..

Comment: WHERE ... AND crb_issues.id = 151

Comment: 151 is NOT static. its dynamic id each time..

Comment: thank you all my problem got solved by Bramer...

Comment: @halfer thank you please. i will be careful next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    crb_issues.id,
    crb_issues.title,
    crb_issues.volume,
    crb_issues.number,
    crb_issues.publish_date,
    crb_issues.is_publish,
    crb_issues.pdfFile,
    crb_issues.flyer,
    crb_issues.cover,
    crb_issues.`status`,
    crb_issues.issueType,
    crbissue_data.typeValue,
    crbissue_data.typeFieldname,
    crbissue_data.typeData,
    crbissue_data.issueId,
    crbissue_data.id
FROM crb_issues
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) id 
            FROM crb_issues
            WHERE crb_issues.is_publish = '1' AND crb_issues.issueType = '0') latest
      ON crb_issues.id = latest.id
INNER JOIN crbissue_data ON crb_issues.id = crbissue_data.issueId
```

Comment: It that's the answer, what was the question?

Comment: He wants to get all the rows for the highest ID in the `crb_issues` table. I moved the `WHERE` clause into the subquery on the assumption that he really means the highest ID that satisfies those conditions.

Comment: @Barmar you are extreme life saver Sir. your query is working perfectly.. that what i want from the my scenrio.... :)

Comment: @Barmar he is absolute right in saying that... a great life saver and expert sql garu..:)

Comment: @Barmar Wouldn't it be safer to have a state defined for the issues instead of relying on SQL queries to sort out the problem? What if some issues are deleted/updated and the highest ID does correspond to the latest record anymore?

Comment: If it's an auto-increment column, the newest rows always get the highest ID. It doesn't fill in gaps left when rows are deleted.

Comment: Well I was more thinking of an update, unless the DB is never to be cleaned up. Anyway...

Comment: @kuroineko Can you explain with me? so i can do that as well.

Comment: Please take this discussion out of the comments on my answer, so I don't get notified of every comment.